# Adding a TikZ canvas in standalone to solve Adobe shading problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading, acrobat

I generated some pictures which, tragically, my linux-Acrobat Reader plugin does not open due to the shadings. Only evince, okular, and light readers do, which solves the problem for me, but not for the people I want to share the file with (who use only Acrobat reader). The code is complicated, but the essential problem is shown already here:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round]
  \shade[draw,upper left=black,upper right=red,
  lower left=blue,lower right=green]
  (0,0) rectangle (1,1); 
 
\node [lightgray!40] at (1.4,1) {some light text practically invisible withouht black background};
  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Acrobat reads it erroneously in pink, while evince (below) does it correctly:

[image]

This makes me think I have to convert the PDFs to a PNG or something like that and then integrate them to my presentation. This presentation is in `beamer` and has a dark canvas and is fine tuned to the size of each `tikz`-pdf image.

I would thus like to either solve the shading problem (which is probably impossible since it's Acrobat Reader-Firefox plugin's fault) or to generate, without modifying the size of the images, for each of the many pictures I use in my presentation, a dark background inside the `standalone` environment in order to later be converted to an image file (so that, having a black background, the light text is visible).

Comment: how do you compile? How old is your tex system?

Comment: Hi Ulrike, thanks for the question. It says: TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.3.1 (ha, I wonder why does it look like π, but not relevant)

Comment: that is the answer for my second question.

Comment: Sorry, I compile with pdflatex

Comment: well you could try to compile with a newer tex system to exclude a possible bug in pgf, e.g. here is an online compiler with a recent system: https://texlive.net/run

Comment: Thank you. Still that online-generator yields a pink background. It's Adobe the culprit.

Comment: what happens if you create a small pdf only with the shading and then include it in another pdf with \includegraphics?

Comment: It still displays the same pink background instead of shading (everthing else correctly). Same whether it's inside beamer or in an article environment. Only Acrobat Reader  displays it incorrectly (not having Windows or Mac, I don't know if it's the plugin). But I think I just could convert after adding `\tikzset{blackground/.style={show background rectangle,tight background,
background rectangle/.style={fill=black}}}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I isolated the problem: it's only firefox Adobe plugin. Opera opens it correctly. Adobe on another computer too. Adobe firefox plugin in other Windows computer again wrong. Thanks for the help above.